# Unnable to download PDF files on API 23 and lower

Tags: java, android, download, android-download-manager

I'm trying to add a class in my application by which I can download different type of files instead of pdf on API 23 and lower.

I have tested my codes on API 24 and upper and I can easily download pdf files but I don't know why it's not working on API <= 23.

```java
public class FileDownloader {
    private static final int MEGA_BYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public interface OnDownloadListener{
        void onStarted();
        void onProgressUpdate(int upd);
        void onFinished(String result);
        void onError(Exception e);
    }

    // usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
    // that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
    public static class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        private Context context;
        private OnDownloadListener onDownloadListener;

        public DownloadTask(Context context, OnDownloadListener onDownloadListener) {
            this.context = context;
            this.onDownloadListener = onDownloadListener;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... str) {
            // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user
            // presses the power button during download
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    getClass().getName());
            wl.acquire();

            try {
                InputStream input = null;
                OutputStream output = null;
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(str[0]);
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.connect();

                    // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
                    // instead of the file
                    if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                                + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();

                    // this will be useful to display download percentage
                    // might be -1: server did not report the length
                    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                    // download the file
                    input = connection.getInputStream();
                    output = new FileOutputStream(str[1]);  //   /sdcard/file_name.extension

                    byte data[] = new byte[MEGA_BYTE];
                    long total = 0;
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        // allow canceling with back button
                        if (isCancelled())
                            return null;
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                            publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if(onDownloadListener != null){
                        onDownloadListener.onError(e);
                    }
                    return e.toString();
                }finally {
                    try {
                        if (output != null)
                            output.close();
                        if (input != null)
                            input.close();
                    }catch (IOException ignored) { }

                    if (connection != null)
                        connection.disconnect();
                }
            } finally {
                wl.release();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(onDownloadListener != null){
                onDownloadListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to fals
            if(onDownloadListener != null){
                onDownloadListener.onProgressUpdate(progress[0]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(onDownloadListener != null){
                onDownloadListener.onFinished(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When "HttpURLConnection" tries to connect it returns error code 404 which means "HTTP 404 Not Found" but on API >= 24 it works fine and also I can download these files via web browsers too. 
I also tried to use "DownloadManager" class but it returns "Failed" when I start downloading pdf files on API <= 23.

How can I fix this problem on API <= 23?!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Set your minSdkVersion to maybe 15. This will make your app compatible with devices API 15 and above